# Android OpenGL-ES Draw expanding line from one point to another

Tags: android, opengl, line, draw

Well im really new to OpenGL but i recently read that using it is the more efficient way to create graphics for androis apps. What i need is create a line that start from a point A and slowly it reaches a predifined point B. I used to do this with canvas - draw methods but it is really slow and it doesnt seem right to me .

```
 package com.example.user.catchthefly_openglproject;

public class DrawTongue{
int StartX;
int StartY;
int StopX;
int StopY;


public DrawTongue(int StartX,int StartY,int StopX,int StopY){
    this.StartX=StartX;
    this.StartY=StartY;
    this.StopX=StopX;
    this.StopY=StopY;
}

public void DrawLine(){
      //here im supposed to draw an expanding line from spot A to spot B 
}

}
```

thank you for you help :) please be as more analytical as you can cause im really new to this !

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to create a line using openGL-es that will progrecivelly extend from point A to point B

Comment: That's too broad of a question...You're asking for a whole tutorial on the basics of OpenGL, which can be found online (see learnopengles.com). But if you're making a game, I recommend trying out LibGDX, which is a much easier starting point than trying to code your own graphics engine if you're a beginner. LibGDX also allows you to test on your PC without the Android emulator, so you can very quickly change code and test it.